# Drop shadow not according to lightsources

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm working with Apriltags in Gazebo and I'm having some lighting issues, the shadows don't respect the light source... or I'm just very noob, most likely.

Is currently selected the sun, as you see the cube drops the shadow in the wrong direction and there is no other light in the world :(

[image]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18492/drop-shadow-not-according-to-lightsources/) by [Cesare](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4554/cesare/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Besides a light's pose, they also have a [direction](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=light#light_direction) property. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/4b4490dc9e938b42d2e9c8c7cce1bad177ad65f5/sun/model.sdf?fileviewer=file-view-default#model.sdf-15)'s where it is defined for the sun.

Unfortunately, the direction is not reflected in the 3D green lines, [nor it is displayed in the world tree](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1405/display-light-direction-on-world-tree). Basically, as a new user, you had no way of knowing it ;)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cesare](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4554/cesare/) on 2018-02-21**:
Hoo, I see... I assumed that the direction would have been derived from the position of the object in the scene, thank you ^_^

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-02-21**:
The position of a directional light is not important, just its orientation. The position of a point light for example would matter.